# Apply existing build configuration to a new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Here is the scenario,

1. Created a new Web application (MVC5, Empty template) as "MyMVCWebApplication".
   Default build configurations are Debug and Release as usual.
2. Import an existing project "Commont.Logger" which has Debug, Release, Test and Prod build configurations.

Once I added the Common.Logger project, VS 2013 show all Debug, Release, Test and Prod configurations in the build configuration drop down list (next to Run).

But I cannot do "Add Config Transform" for the web config (for Test and Prod) in the web project. 
Then I checked the "Configuration Manager", I noticed that it does not show Test and Prod configurations for the web project. In the Edit configuration it only has Rename and Remove, no "Add" function.

How can I add these Test and Prod build configurations to the Web project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

When tools does not work or there are no tools only option is to get your hands dirty by manually editing the sln file.

This is FYI,

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Dev|Any CPU = Azure_Dev|Any CPU
    PreProd|Any CPU = Azure_PreProd|Any CPU
    Test|Any CPU = Azure_Test|Any CPU
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU       
    Prod|Any CPU = Prod|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Dev|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Dev|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.PreProd|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.PreProd|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Test|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Test|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Dev|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Dev|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Prod|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Prod|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
............more....
```

Here is my observation.

Assume the project Id "8D475C27-8BAF-4B5E-8D65-729A8541B14F" is the imported project.

When you "Add Existing Projects" with different build configurations which are not in the "New Project" (MyMVCWebApplication), and compile, you will get those new build configurations in the imported project in the "Global Section" of the Solution file. That's why you can see those configurations in the "Visual Studio"'s environments dropdown (Debug, Release,... drop down).

Inspecting the Sln file (open with notepad) I noticed that these new build configurations does not get added to projects in "MyMVCWebApplication" in GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) section. As you can see each project Id has two lines per environment as CPU.Build.0 and CPU.ActiveCfg.
Web project has these record only for Dev and Release.

Solution:
Added configurations to Solutionfile for the WebProject referring to the existing project.

Comment: I, too, ran into this problem. What worked for me was adding <PropertyGroup> sections in the relevant proj files with the missing configuration values (example:   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Staging|AnyCPU'">...
  </PropertyGroup>). It was basically the same idea as your answer, so I won't post another answer, but I'm leaving this comment in case some else runs into the same problem and the solution edit doesn't quite do the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: In addition to the answer and @MichaelArmes comment I also needed a property (in the first property group with the project guid and output type) of `<Configurations>List;Of;My;Configurations</Configurations>`. This wasn't necessary for all .csproj files but rather only some.

Answer (score 8):

In the Configuration Manager (Build menu) you see a list of the projects.
In the column Configuration you have a dropdown list. At the bottom of that list you have the option `<New...>`

**update:**
As mentioned in the comments, this does not work straight away.
Today I had a similar situation:

1. When adding  the new configuration, in the Configuration Manager, I unchecked "*Create new solution configurations*" and clicked ok.
2. I set the config in the Toolbar to the desired one (Development)
3. I right clicked on the app.config and from the context menu selected Add Transform (Slow Cheetah).

That added the app.Development.config

Comment: with "New" you can't add the same Prod configuration (gives an error saying name already exists).

Comment: Thinking out of the box: if you first remove the configuration in the imported project? And add the configuration to both the projects?

Comment: Perhaps the tool SlowCheetah can help.

Comment: I am using slow cheetah, it only works for app.configs. But this is regarding a webconfig in the web project.

Comment: @Dhanuka777 - It does work if you name it the same as an existing configuration - but you MUST have "Create new Solution configurations" unchecked as per step 1 in the above answer